# Entity design advice for following relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following business case needs:

1. I have a database of projects.
2. Each project will have several people associated with it in different roles(project owners, support, etc).
3. A single person may play multiple roles in the project.
4. A persons' contact details on a project are captured at the time of project creation and should not be updated for that project when they are updated for the person.

I have the following database structure proposed:

[image]

ContactDetails is planned as a 1-1 for now, but seperated in the event that multiple person/role mappings for a single project could share a single ContactDetail.

My question:
Typically I will be loading the list of associated people with my project in their various roles. Based on the structure I have laid out, what should my entity look like here: has ProjectPerson become the entity as opposed to just a cross reference (as it started out being)?

**[UPDATE]**

Including my new data structure based on the below answer in case it helps anyone else. As advised.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the contact details into ProjectPeople and pull the roles out into a separate table with a one-to-many relationship to ProjectPeople.

To answer your question, yes ProjectPerson is now an entity in your domain model; in fact, I would say it became one as soon as it became more than a simple many-to-many mapping table.

We have a similar structure and it presents some challenges. I have it modeled so that Project has a collection of ProjectPerson and Person has a read-only collection of Project.

Comment: Thank you for validating this for me. Roles is already an Enum in an additional table, just not shown for clarity, in hindsight should have shown for clarity :).

Comment: I was referring to TeamRoleId in ProjectPeople and assuming that was the person's role. If a person can have multiple roles on a project, I would pull that out into a ProjectPeopleRole table. I would also move the fields from ContactDetails into ProjectPeople.

Comment: Ok - following you now. I see how that is a much cleaner approach to roles than I was planning, and agreed that it removes my need of a separate contact details table by simplifying the approach

Comment: Also - thank you very much for taking the time to revisit my comment and ensuring understanding!